Make layout in swing wrap contents height
i'm trying to create a IntelliJ plugin using swing.
When i use FlowLayout in one of the panels it pushes the next view to the bottom of the screen.
I would prefer to no set a max height so it can be responsive.
How can i make it so the items view doesn't expand the entire screen?



How it looks
What i want









Here is my window:
class ToolWindow : ToolWindowFactory {

    override fun createToolWindowContent(project: Project, window: ToolWindow) {
        val panel = JPanel()
        panel.layout = BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)

        panel.add(JLabel("Main Title"))

        val itemPanel = JPanel()
        itemPanel.layout = FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5)
        itemPanel.add(JLabel("Item A"))
        itemPanel.add(JLabel("Item B"))
        panel.add(itemPanel)

        panel.add(JLabel("Subtitle"))

        val contentManager = window.contentManager
        val content = contentManager.factory.createContent(panel, null, false)
        window.contentManager.addContent(content)
    }
}

